# How to make 4 gradient color on 4 side, each color make a triangle gradient in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

The question is a little confusing, just look at this example of gradient that I want to make.
[image: example]

This what I have tried, I used mesh tool for 4 sides of the rectangle with 4 colors but didn't give a result that I expected

What should I do properly, I'm new to Illustrator

[image: mywork]

Comment: You need a conical gradient: https://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-create-a-conical-gradient-with-adobe-illustrator-in-two-minutes--vector-3898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Create four triangles that make a square.
- Colour each triangle as required.
- Group the triangles.
- Apply a blur to the group.

Comment: Although it does not look 100% the same, thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's a simple vector solution: draw the rectangle form with rounded corners. Seperately, draw the circular vector gradient, i.e. 4 colors, 90° apart. Then turn the gradient 45° and put it inside the rectangle (mask it, use the rectangle as a amsk for the gradient. Center it horizontally and vertically. And done. Now you can scale the gradient and its mask seperately.

Comment: Not sure this is what the OP is looking for. Can you please edit and add some images to support your solution? thanks

Comment: Can you add some images?